# How can I program on the GPU in Unity?

Tags: unity, gpu, gpgpu

In my [previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17074/are-there-any-benefits-for-using-the-cpu-instead-of-the-gpu), I asked about why people don't program on the GPU. Now I am learning about fluid dynamics with this [article](http://developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch38.html). They say that it should all be done on the GPU. The game engine that I use is Unity, and I know that shaders are run on the GPU. But is there any way to program (other than shaders) on the GPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertex and pixel shaders are the primary way that graphics programming on the GPU is done.  However, more recent GPUs also support some technologies for more general-purpose parallel programming, such as [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html) (NVIDIA only), [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/), and most recently compute shaders (on DirectX 11 GPUs; google for more info about them).  I don't think CUDA or OpenCL can effectively interchange data with the graphics pipeline, but compute shaders can.

Comment: What about PhysX?

Comment: PhysX can use the GPU, yes.  But that's not really programming on the GPU, since the GPU stuff is already done for you by the PhysX developers.

Answer (score 2):

Use Compute shaders (DirectX 11) or OpenCL on desktop systems.